# Java - List, types, and Inheritance (maybe generic?)

Tags: java, list, generics, inheritance, types

Lets say I have a class of type **Color**. I want to create some child classes, **Red**, **Green**, and **Blue**. Then, in a completely separate class I have a List called **Rainbow** of type **Color**. I want to be able to place all types of colors (**Red, Greed, Blue**) into the list **Rainbow** that way later I can search the list **Rainbow** by a type of color to see if it contains one of those colors. Here is some pseudocode of what I'm wanting to accomplish:

```
class Color(){}
class Red extends Color(){}
class Blue extends Color(){}
class Green extends Color(){}
class JustSomeClass(){
    List<Color> Rainbow;
    Rainbow.add(new Red());
    Rainbow.add(new Blue());
    Rainbow.add(new Green());

    public Color getTypeOfColor(typeOfColor){
        for(Color c : Rainbow){
            if(c.getType().equals(typeOfColor)){
                return c;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not that familiar enough with Java to know a good way to go about accomplishing this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Pertty much exactly the code you wrote will work.  What part seems to concern you?

Comment: What does `Color` do? Could you maybe use an [`enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) and a `switch`? Or, otherwise, a Visitor Pattern would be better.

Comment: Move `Rainbow.add(new Red());` calls inside the constructor or method.

Comment: Without more details it is hard for us to tell you if this is a good approach. How are you going to use this? Why do you need to check the color? Can't you check the color using a hash instead?

Comment: **Downvoter** Let me know what is wrong with `Map<String,Color>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things you should consider.  Collections (like `List`) use both the `hashCode()` method and the `equals()` method to do their work.  You must override those methods for your class `Color` so that the Collection knows what to do.

After that, then you should think about what `Color` really does.  Is each color unique?  Can your Rainbow have more than one Color in it?  If not (each color Red is the same as all colors) use a Set.  If there's more than one flavor (more than one concrete type of red) then your list is probably better.

Here's the Set one.  When run, it prints `false`, then `true`.

```
public class RainbowTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Set<Color> rainbow = new HashSet<>();
      rainbow.add(new Red(.1f));
      rainbow.add(new Blue(.1f));
      rainbow.add(new Green(.1f));
      System.out.println(rainbow.contains(new Blue(.5f)));
      System.out.println(rainbow.contains(new Red(.1f)));
   }
}

abstract class Color {
   private final float intensity;

   public Color(float intensity) {
      this.intensity = intensity;
   }

   public float getIntensity() {
      return intensity;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      int hash = 3;
      hash = 83 * hash + Float.floatToIntBits(this.intensity);
      return hash;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (obj == null)
         return false;
      if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
         return false;
      final Color other = (Color) obj;
      if( this.intensity != other.intensity )
         return false;
      return true;
   }

}

class Red extends Color {

   public Red( float intensity ) {
      super( intensity );
   }

}
class Green extends Color {

   public Green( float intensity ) {
      super( intensity );
   }

}
class Blue extends Color {

   public Blue( float intensity ) {
      super( intensity );
   }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain further what exactally you are doing with hashCode?

Comment: Actually, that's a large question, probably one you should post here as a question by itself.  You can see a good example of [how Java's hash code works at Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29).  There's also [numerous websites with additional information.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05273/)  In short, the answer is long and better suited to its own question.

Answer (score 0):

A generic <colour> won't allow it's sub class
Use it as <T extends color>

Comment: Sorry, yes a generic list can have members of its subclasses.  See my answer for working code.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a class RainBow which would extend a concrete implementation of List. 
This is since a RainBow actually **IS** a list of colors.

```
public class RainBow extends ArrayList<Color> {

public void addColor(Color color)
{
    this.add(color);
}

public Color getTypeOfColor(String typeOfColor){
    for(Color c : this){
        if(c.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(typeOfColor)){
            return c;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

You can then use this class like so :

```
    Red red = new Red();
    Blue blue = new Blue();
    Rainbow rainbow = new Rainbow();
    rainbow.add(red);
    rainbow.add(blue);
    if (rainbow.getTypeOfColor("Yellow") == null) {
        //Color doesn't exist
    }
    if (rainbow.getTypeOfColor("Red") != null) {
        //Color exists
    }
```

Be aware this uses the class names for the comparisation.